require does not work when moving to other pages
navbar.php
<?php
require 'config.php';

$admin = new Admin();

if (isset($_SESSION['user_id'])) {
    $user_id = $_SESSION['user_id'];
    $res = $admin->ret("SELECT * FROM `user` WHERE `user_id` = '$user_id'");
    $user = $res->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    }
?>

When I am at index.php page it works fine and requires the config.php
But when I move to other pages it shows an error

Warning
: require(config.php): Failed to open stream: No such file or directory in
C:\xampp\htdocs\Web\includes\navbar.php
on line
2


Fatal error
: Uncaught Error: Failed opening required 'config.php' (include_path='C:\xampp\php\PEAR') in C:\xampp\htdocs\Web\includes\navbar.php:2 Stack trace: #0 C:\xampp\htdocs\Web\views\auth\auth.php(20): include() #1 {main} thrown in
C:\xampp\htdocs\Web\includes\navbar.php
on line
2



Have a look at https://phpdelusions.net/articles/paths . config.php is in the root of your site, so relative to anything in includes, it's one level up in the filesystem

Unrelated to current question but you should be using prepared statements and parameterized queries.

This is a problem of path.
As per the image you provided, you have the following structure:

index.php and config.php are in the same directory (root)
navbar.php is nested in a subdirectory (includes)

Now, the require 'config.php' line in your script references to no folder at all, which means PHP will look in the same directory as the calling script.

index.php will look in the root directory, and will find config.php there
navbar.php will look in the includes subdirectory... and config.php won't be there!

The solution is to specify a path to your config.php file. For example:
require '/config.php'
